# Conditional rendering of object INSIDE array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, conditional-rendering

I have an array cars of objects. I want to insert the object with header: AUDI only if audi is true.

```
var audi = false;
var cars= [
   {header: 'fiat',accessor: row},
   {header: 'audi',accessor: row},
   {header: 'bmw',accessor: row}
]
```

I tried with ternary operator but cars doesn't accept empty object {}. So is there a way to simulate what we usually do for conditional rendering? (ex: audi &&{...} ) THANKS <3

```
var audi = false;
var cars= [
   {header: 'fiat',accessor: row},
   audi?{header: 'audi',accessor: row}:{},
   {header: 'bmw',accessor: row}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var audi = false;
var cars= [
   {header: 'fiat',accessor: row},
   {header: 'audi',accessor: row},
   {header: 'bmw',accessor: row}
].filter(car => audi || car.header !== 'audi')
```

Or [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var audi = false;
var cars= [
   {header: 'fiat',accessor: row},
   ...(audi ? [
      {header: 'audi',accessor: row}
   ] : []),
   {header: 'bmw',accessor: row}
]
```